# How to compile Reason JSX functions that don't use children

Tags: jsx, reason

[Note: I'm referring to pure Reason JSX functions **not** Reason React PPX]

Given a JSX function that doesn’t use children:

```
let f = (~foo, ~children, ()) => foo;
<f foo="a" />;
```

Attempting to compile this with [`dune build`](https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick-start.html) yields this error, which seems to prevent an executable from being created:

```
line 1, characters 16-24:
Warning 27: unused variable children.
File "hello_world.re", line 1:
Error: Some fatal warnings were triggered (1 occurrences)
```

Marking the children parameter as unused with an underscore:

```
let f = (~foo, ~_children, ()) => foo;
<f foo="a" />;
```

Yields an error about expecting children from the JSX call:

```
line 2, characters 7-10:
Error: This expression has type bytes but an expression was expected of type
         children:'a -> 'b
```

Is there way to compile JSX functions that don't use children?

Comment: `children` should not be a named argument. The normal way of defining the component is, as per the documentation: `let f = (~foo, _children) => {...};`

Comment: As far as I know there's no such thing as a function component in Reason JSX either. Maybe [try reading the documentation](https://reasonml.github.io/reason-react/docs/en/jsx)?

Comment: @glennsl I'm not using React. Lowercase JSX calls in Reason become function calls: https://reasonml.github.io/docs/en/jsx#uncapitalized-tag

Comment: @Yawar thanks! What documentation are you referring to? I didn't see this mentioned in the JSX documentation: https://reasonml.github.io/docs/en/jsx. I'm happy to send a pull request to add it there unless there's a better place that I've missed.

Comment: @Yawar I receive an error about the number of arguments when doing what you described: https://reasonml.github.io/en/try?rrjsx=false&reason=DYUwLgBAZhC8EAoB+UD2qA0ED6BjAFgJbAAmATiAHYCUcAfBAN4C+A3AFAA8MaqsAREX4QA9HVaiAVBACSkVJWABPCAENcuEAAcwAZwgBGNWQDmAVwC2VMBPwgKWQmADk+3KuCgSEAO5P8EBaoFAB0EJIi7FFAA

Comment: @Robz Right, sorry. Don't you think that would have been worth a mention though, seeing as it's pretty much exclusively used with the RR PPX? It seems @Yawar is assuming the same. Anyway, I don't think what you're doing is (only) marking the parameter as unused, but  rather renaming it externally as well. Try `~children as _children` instead.

Comment: @glennsl awesome, that works! I'm still getting the hang of labeled/renamed arguments, but I think I get it now. Feel free to mention that as an answer and I'll accept. About RR PPX: I've never used it (pretty new to reason here!), but I see from the confusion I've caused that it's pretty popular--I edited my question to call that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `~_children` does not just rename the parameter internally and mark it as unused, but renames it externally as well. So `~children` is no longer part of the function signature.

Instead you should use `as` to just rename it internally, which still also marks it as unused:

```
let f = (~foo, ~children as _children, ()) => foo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Would making it an optional parameter work?

```
let f = (~foo, ~children=?, ()) => foo;
<f foo="a"/>
```

Comment: Looks like this also results in a warning about having an unused parameter: https://reasonml.github.io/en/try?rrjsx=false&reason=DYUwLgBAZhC8EAoB+UD2qA0EkGMAWAlsACYBOIAdrAPxYICU9cAfNOgNwBQAPDGqrABEAQ0EB6ZkA

Comment: then just use `~_children=?`

Comment: that yields an error "This has type: string But somewhere wanted: children:'a -> 'b": https://reasonml.github.io/en/try?rrjsx=false&reason=DYUwLgBAZhC8EAoB+UD2qA0EkH0DGAFgJbAAmATiAHawD8WCAlI3AHzToDcAUADwxpUsAEQBDYQHpWQA

Comment: Oops sorry, I tested it on `~_test=?` and it worked because it wasn't expected.

Comment: I think the best way is to just ignore the warning with the above code